# What does application/json++protobuf mean?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, grpc

Using google maps js api, I saw this request: `GetViewportInfo`.

- request url

https://maps.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.maps.mapsjs.v1.MapsJsInternalService/GetViewportInfo

---

- request header

Content-Type: application/json+protobuf
X-User-Agent: grpc-web-javascript/0.1

---

- request body

```
[[[37.51873574202641,126.90496516662532],[37.565940612678745,126.99632943240402]],16,null,"ko-KR",0,"m@676000000",0,0,null,null,null,1,"http://localhost:5500/js-api/index.html",1]
```

What does `application/json + protobuf` mean?
Does this request use gRPC or not?

Comment: The request body is JSON and doesn't appear to include any protobuf binary (base64-encoded fields in JSON) encoded data. The URL is not gRPC either although it looks to include an RPC-like `{package}.{service}/{method}` name. I suspect the protocol is HTTP1.1 (not 2.0 which would be used by gRPC). Google uses gRPC internally and increasingly publishes the services as gRPC external (see [Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis)).

Comment: Historically services were transcoded to HTTP/JSON but there was (and I can only find this reference [Google Protocol RPC](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/tools/protorpc)) an early RPC mechanism). Maps may still use older RPC mechanism. It's unclear. I was unable to find references to `application/json+protobuf` but the `google.internal` prefix in the service's package (?) name suggests this endpoint isn't intended for non-Google SDKs and so you may be challenged to use it directly.